# NVIDIA installer fails when upgrading kernel

Tags: drivers, nvidia, upgrade, compiling, gcc

I got the following problem on 18.04:

- GCC was updated from GCC 7.3 to GCC 7.4
- A new kernel was installed (compiled with 7.3)

Now the NVIDIA driver will not install as it requires that the installed version was also used to compile the kernel.

I tried the IGNORE_CC_MISMATCH without success. What is the preferred way of solving the problem:

- Recompile the kernel package with the current gcc
- Downgrade GCC to 7.3

I guess one should file a bug to canonical (title: Always deploy kernels compiled with current version of GCC).

Comment: You should install the version in the repository. You can use Additional Drivers for that. Do not install the binary from Nvidia.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Sometimes, that package is broken too

Comment: It's possible but very unlikely, rarely.

Comment: You need to download the latest Nvidia driver that is compatible with your Kernel version you can download it from nvidia website or use the proprietary drivers from Ubuntu.

Comment: @JoKeR even beta drivers from nvidia website complain about this... seems they need to recompile the driver with latest gcc , im stuck

Comment: use `sudo sh ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-*.run --no-cc-version-check` I believe NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-*.run is unsetting IGNORE_CC_MISMATCH unless you use the --no-cc-version-check flag.  See https://askubuntu.com/a/1143434/144906

Comment: i have posted a bug report on launchpad you may add yourself to the affected list to get https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1829598

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change which gcc version you use by running

```
sudo update-alternatives --config gcc
```

It will list you installed version of gcc and you can set any gcc version as default.